# Different path formats for PostgreSQL JSONB functions

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-12

I'm confused by how *path* uses different formats depending on the function in the [PostgreSQL JSONB documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html).

If I had a PostgreSQL table *foo* that looks like

| pk | json_obj |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | `{"values": [{"id": "a_b", "value": 5}, {"id": "c_d", "value": 6]}` |
| 1 | `{"values": [{"id": "c_d", "value": 7}, {"id": "e_f", "value": 8]}` |

Why does this query give me these results?

```sql
SELECT json_obj,                                          -- {"values": [{"id": "a_b", "value": 5}, {"id": "c_d", "value": 6]}
       json_obj @? '$.values[*].id',                      -- true
       json_obj #> '$.values[*].id',                      -- ERROR: malformed array literal
       json_obj #> '{values, 0, id}',                     -- "a_b"
       JSONB_SET(json_obj, '$.annotations[*].id', '"hi"') -- ERROR: malformed array literal
FROM foo;
```

Specifically, why does `@?` support `$.values[*].id` (described on that page in another [section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)) but `JSONB_SET` uses some other path format `{bar,3,baz}`?

Ultimately, what I would like to do and don't know how, is to remove non-alphanumeric characters (e.g. underscores in this example) in all `id` values represented by the path `$.values[*].id`.

Comment: Because  `@?` supports [SQL/JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) and `#>` does not. `jsonb_set()` and `#>` were introduced before Postgres supported SQL/JSON path (I think even before SQL/JSON path was included into the SQL standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the operators have different data types on the right hand side.

```
SELECT oprname, oprright::regtype
FROM pg_operator
WHERE oprleft = 'jsonb'::regtype
  AND oprname IN ('@?', '#>');

 oprname | oprright 
---------+----------
 #>      | text[]
 @?      | jsonpath
(2 rows)
```

Similarly, the second argument of `jsonb_set` is a `text[]`.

Now `'$.values[*].id'` is a valid `jsonpath`, but not a valid `text[]` literal.

Comment: What operators are valid for the `test[]` parameter of `jsonb_set` function and how do they work? I couldn't find a list, only saw in examples that a number seems to mean _item at index_ and a string a _property in an object_, anything else?

Comment: @FireEmerald That looks like a new question.

Comment: Okay, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77986770/4300087

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and comments about why the data types were different.

I wanted to post how I solved my problem:

> Ultimately, what I would like to do and don't know how, is to remove
> non-alphanumeric characters (e.g. underscores in this example) in all
> `id` values represented by the path `$.values[*].id`.

```sql
WITH unnested AS (
    SELECT f.pk, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(f.json_obj -> 'values') AS value
    FROM foo f
),
updated_values AS (
    SELECT un.pk, JSONB_SET(un.value, '{id}', TO_JSONB(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(un.value ->> 'id', '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', 'g'))), FALSE) AS new_value
    FROM unnested un
    WHERE value -> 'id' IS NOT NULL -- Had some values that didn't have 'id' keys
)
UPDATE foo f2
SET json_obj = JSONB_SET(f2.json_obj, '{values}', (SELECT JSONB_AGG(uv.new_value) FROM updated_values uv WHERE uv.pk = f2.pk), FALSE)
WHERE JSONB_PATH_EXISTS(f2.json_obj, '$.values[*].id') -- Had some values that didn't have 'id' keys
```