# Explain parameter 'path' (text[]) of postgres function jsonb_set

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Which values are valid for the `path text[]` parameter of the `jsonb_set` function and how are they interpreted? Numbers vs. strings vs. something else?

```sql
jsonb_set(target         jsonb,
          path           text[], /* <-- ??? */
          new_value      jsonb,
          create_missing boolean default true)
```

Especially if the queried json is a complex object like `{"Id": 1, "Values": {"Name": "Doe", "Online": [10,20,30]}}` and not a simple array.

```
obj = '{"Id": 1, "Values": {"Name": "Doe", "Online": [10,20,30]}}'

SELECT jsonb_set(obj, '{Values,0}', '99');
-> {"Id": 1, "Values": {"0": 99, "Name": "Doe", "Online": [10, 20, 30]}}

SELECT jsonb_set(obj, '{Values,Online,0}', '99');
-> {"Id": 1, "Values": {"Name": "Doe", "Online": [99, 20, 30]}}
```

And yes i read the docu [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), but they always only say *"Returns target with the item designated by path"* - and how is **"path"** defined, works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty clearly described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) of the `#>` operator, where you can find

> the specified path, where path elements can be either field keys or array indexes

Admittedly, that information is not repeated in the description of `jsonb_set()`.

Comment: I didn't know that the `path` of `jsonb_set()` has the same behavior as the `#>` operator. If you know where to search or look, everything is _clearly described_ ;)

Comment: I agree that the documentation could be improved here.